# Where to get Authorization Key for IBM Chef Watson API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

Can anyone please guide me where to get authorization key for Chef Watson API referred from [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/apidocs/95-chef-watson?&language=node#introduction)?

*Or* is there any test API Explorer for this API such like [this](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/personality-insights-v3#!/personality45insights/profile) for Personality Insights, where don't need to put credentials?
I also looked for this (Chef Watson API) in Bluemix catalog but unable to find, so is there anyway to get rid of this issue or has IBM closed this API support?

Thanks.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ChefWatson API is marked experimental in the documentation you linked above. Experimental services can be found in the [Bluemix Labs Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/labs/).

Experimental services often do not make it to Beta (let alone GA) but they are placed in the labs catalog so that users can play with them and the product teams can gather usage metrics.

My best guess is that the ChefWatson API has since been removed from the labs catalog and is no longer available.

You might be able to achieve some of what you're trying to do by interrogating the API hosted for https://www.ibmchefwatson.com/

It requires you to understand the ingredient IDs (I couldn't find a list) but after you've got that you can return matches for that ingredient.

As an example - the results for the ingredient 'chicken' can be found like so:
https://www.ibmchefwatson.com/IronChefUI/jaxrs/recipe/tuples?q&ingredientid=1154

Comment: This same question was asked on dW Answers at the following URL:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/374024/where-to-get-authorization-key-for-chef-watson-api.html

The Chef Watson service is not listed in the Bluemix Labs Catalog; only the API catalog. We are researching why the information exists in the API catalog and will likely remove it.

Comment: Thanks @BillWentworth